# TypeScript function that conditionally returns a react-router route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a TypeScript function, that when invoked, returns a `react-router-dom` route based conditionally on the parameter provided. However, when I declare the return type of `(Route | null)`, I get the following error:

> TS2740: Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type
>   'Route': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 2
>   more.

Am I not correctly declaring the return type for this function, and if so, what should it be? I also tried `(Route<RouteProps> | null)` but that did not seem to solve the problem. Thanks.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const SampleComponent: React.FC = () => <h1>hello world</h1>;

export const getRoute = (returnRoute: boolean): (Route | null) => {
  if (returnRoute) {
    return (
      <Route
        component={SampleComponent}
        exact
        path="/samplePath"
      />
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the signature of a `Route`..

```
export class Route<T extends RouteProps = RouteProps> extends React.Component<T, any> { }
```

you'll see that it's just a class. In your return you're saying that you're returning an instance of that class (i.e. `new Route(props)`) or `null`, and not a component of that class (a `ReactNode`). It's the same idea as if you're having a function that is returning a `React.Component`

A React.ReactNode is basically a set of valid return values for React components:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

So to answer your question, you can replace `(Route | null)` by `React.ReactNode`.